# Android change default permission protection level

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-source

I want to build android from the source in-order to grant certain level permission for my app to function.

I came to this [AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) which seams that changing the permissions protection level can change this permission in android rom.

like

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA_PROJECTION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

to

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA_PROJECTION"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

my question is this whether this apporch works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'll likely work.

But by doing this, you'll be "allowing" other apps to do that to. The proper way to handle this would be to sign your application with the platform certificate, and you'll be allowed to request such permissions.